# Angular Bootstrap split dropdown button not working

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get bootstrap dropdown list working on plnkr but it is not dropping down the list, I have created a plunk here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tw3O5ihT7YB79BcAGlsh

This code was copied from bootstrap:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <!-- Split button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="a in vm.exportAction">
          <a ng-if="a.visble == true">
            <span ng-click="vm.selectedExport(a)">{{a.action}}</span>
          </a>
          <div ng-if="a.divider == true">
            <div role="separator" class="divider"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Jquery` and `Bootstrap` JavaScript files in `head` after `Bootstrap's` CSS - [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6X1dna31WBO0Om9f6Qt?p=preview):

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```